# Check who sent dm to bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I've tried to get the id from `message.member.id` but it returned `null`

This is how the bot replies when in a guild:
[image: Bot replies with the id of the author]

When used in a DM, the bot does not reply since `message.member.id` is `null`:
[image: The bot does not reply]

Could anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

[`Message.member.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) doesn't work in DMs, since the user didn't send the message in a guild (and so is not a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)).
If you want to get the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object of the author of the message, you should simply use [`Message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author)

Answer (score 0):

message.member.id doesn't work in dms.
create a variable like :

> var user = message.author

and to get id, us :

> user.id